# How can I produce better spacing between header and content when using fancyhdr package?

Tags: spacing, fancyhdr

I am currently using the `fancyhdr` package with the following setup:

```
%BOOK FORMATTING
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                       % nice header format
    \fancyhead[RO, LE]{\textbsf{\thepage}}      % page numbers, on both odd and even
    \fancyhead[LO]{\textbsf{\leftmark}}         % chapter headings
    \fancyhead[RE]{\textbsf{\rightmark}}        % section headings
```

with the `\pagestyle{fancy}` option. This produces the following output:

[image: Current output (minimal spacing between headers and content)]

However, I require more space between the header and the main content because it looks a little cramped right now. Sometimes, also, `Large` font sizes trespass through the header, which is unsightly, although I couldn't find an example of this in my current document.

How can I introduce more space between the header and main content?

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: are you not getting warnings from the package that you need to increase `\headheight` ?

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, should I be?
@juanuni I am using the `book` class.

Comment: that would be my guess but people can only guess as you have given only fragments of code. make a small one-page document that shows the problem and post the whole thing into your question, so people can reproduce,